# Getting Error while creating the Virtual User

Tags: security, user-management

We are using ADFS Authenticator module, when we are trying to create a virtual user, we are getting the below error:

> Expecting state ‘Element’.. Encountered ‘Text’ with name ”, namespace
>   ”.

Below is the code I am using in my applications.

`Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User vuser =
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(“athakur”, true);`

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: You may need to include a domain in the first parameter passed to `BuildVirtualUser`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
                //Specify with the domain name
                var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(String.Format("extranet\\{0}", user.Email), true);

                // You can add roles to the Virtual user                    virtualUser.Roles.Add(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName("extranet\\Anonymous"));

                // You can even work with the profile if you wish
                virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("CustomProperty", user.UserName);
                virtualUser.Profile.Email = user.Email;
                virtualUser.Profile.Name = user.DisplayName;
                virtualUser.Profile.FullName = user.UserName;

                virtualUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Country", user.Country);

                //And finally, if you wish to login the virtual user                    Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

Comment: this code works for sitecore 9.3 version too?